# Как изменить цвет значков в статусбаре?

Tags: android

После изменения цвета статусбара появилась проблема, значки в статусбаре остались белого цвета. Что необходимо прописать в styles.xml, чтобы можно было изменить цвет значков?

[image: Статусбар]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В res/values-v23/styles.xml внутри стиля укажите

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

Или просто в коде activity

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
}
```

Это сделает иконки статус бара темными. Работает только на версиях api >= 23. Насколько я знаю, на более младших версияx цвет значков поменять нельзя